# Set double variable to value of another variable

Tags: c++

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here. With the code I've posted, how do I set the double 'condition' to the value of the double 'interstate' ?. I thought by entering 'interstate' as the answer to my 'cout' question would work. The calculation I get is garbage.

```
double multiplyAmount(double overage)
{
    double interstate = 1.25;
    double countyRd = 2.23;
    double condition;
    double result;

    cout << "Enter condition of road: ";
    cin >> condition;

    result = overage * condition;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You need to read a string and then have a map<string, double> and after reading string searching for the double value.

Comment: You ask the user for a `double`.  Entering the text `interstate` is not a `double`. If you want the user to enter text you need a `std::string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable *names* are purely lexical, meaning they do not exist outside of compilation process (e.g. do not exist at runtime when user enters something).

There are many ways to achieve what you want.

Here's one of them:

```
#include <string>

double multiplyAmount(double overage)
{
    double interstate = 1.25;
    double countyRd = 2.23;
    double condition;
    double result;
    string conditionInput;

    cout << "Enter condition of road: ";
    cin >> conditionInput;

    if(conditionInput=="interstate") {
        condition = interstate;
    } else if(conditionInput=="countryRd") {
        condition = countryRd;
    } else {
        cout << "Unknown condition" << conditionInput << std::endl;
        abort();
    }

    result = overage * condition;

    return result;
}
```